# Whats wrong with this group join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a Profile class that has a father property which self references to itself, I want to load a profile together with its fathers profile in one sql join statement

```
Select * FROM profile left join profile as father on profile.fatherid = father.id where profile.id = 650
```

So i created the following linq statement, but instead of running the sql statement about it runs the following statements

```
select * from profiles

select * from profiles where id = 650
```

Then in memory it groups them together, but obviously i would not want to load the whole database.

```
    private class Result
    {
        public Profile Profile { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Profile> Fathers { get; set; }
    }
    private Result MapFather(Profile p, IEnumerable<Profile> father)
    {
        return new Result() {Profile = p, Fathers = father.DefaultIfEmpty()};
    }

   var profiles = from p in db.Profiles where p.ID.Equals(650) select p;
   var fathers = from f in db.Profiles select f;
   var groupJoin = profiles.GroupJoin(fathers,
                                        p => p.FatherID, 
                                        f => f.ID, 
                                        MapFather).ToList();
```

Comment: Your statement may be too complicated for LINQ to parse as a single SQL statement.  Can you write your GroupJoin in a single C# LINQ statement?

Comment: Excuse me if I am not so  skilled with linq, but is this not fetching the whole table? You are fetching the ID then group joining (comparing to all reconrds) in the same table on another field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to GroupJoin() is getting the IEnumerable version because of your call to MapFather is a Func<,> instead of Expression>. Therefore the calls to profiles and fathers are being executed before the GroupJoin.

Try inlining MapFather():

```
var groupJoin = profiles.GroupJoin(fathers,
                                    p => p.FatherID, 
                                    f => f.ID, 
                                    (p, fathers) => new Result() {Profile = p, Fathers = father.DefaultIfEmpty()}).ToList();
```

Comment: And how would i do this as an expression?